# is there any generic way to check os.Stdin or input redirected from null device?

Tags: windows, go

I would like to check input is redirected to null device or not in go language.I got one way for unix but I don't how to deal with windows or make it generic.This is what I did for unix

```
fd := os.Stdin.Fd()
fmt.Print(fmt.Sprint("/proc/self/fd/", fd))
fileName, err1 := os.Readlink(fmt.Sprint("/proc/self/fd/", fd))

if err1 != nil {
    fmt.Print(err1)
}
fmt.Println("fileName:", fileName)
```

Comment: What would this be used for?

Comment: I used (if it is null device) for giving warning before prompting for input

Comment: What exactly would constitute a generic, cross platform, null device? In what case does it make sense to prompt for input when there is no way to get input?

Comment: I would like to check input is redirect to null device or not.I think its specific to platform.Example for windows NUL and for unix /dev/null.I just want to know is there any common way